# Using vba code to control a button (class selectpicker instead of select or formfield) in a html webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba

I would like to connect automatically fo the following web pages:
https://ssologin-bp2s.bnpparibas.com/SSOLoginAction.do
To do that I need to move the green button (close to "Authentification" label) to "CarteSecure Id" and I cannot figure out how to move that button. Below the html code

```
       <div class="row form-group">
          <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label" for="authenthication">Authentification :</label>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
             <select name="authLevels" id="authLevels"  class="selectpicker" data-width="auto" data-style="btn-success">
                <option value="1">Standard</option>
                <option value="2">Carte SecurId</option>
                <option value="3">Certificat iPKI</option>

                <option value="4">BNP Paribas</option>

             </select>
```

I have tried several options on VBA, like

With ie.document

```
.getElementById("userId").Value = user

.getElementById("password").Value = pwd



.getElementById("authLevels").selectedIndex = 2
.getElementById("authLevels").Value = "2"
```

But nothing's working I believe that it does not work because the class is selectpicker and not like formfield or select. I might be wrong of course.

If anyone could put me in the right direction.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The select box you see in the page source is hidden and dynamically replaced by the green button

Try using both:

```
.getElementById("authLevels").selectedIndex = 1 'set the hidden list: zero-based!
.getElementById("authLevel").value = 2          'a hidden field associated with the green button
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for answering I really appreciate but unfortunately that button is still in the same position and doesn't move

Comment: @Eric - the standard select list defined in the page source appears briefly as the page loads (if you turn off javascript you will see it), but on page load it's replaced by the "green button", which is not a standard HTML select but some kind of custom widget.  So, it doesn't have a `selectedIndex` (as it's not a `select` element)